# Keeping a zero when pasting

Tags: r

I have the Table below. I need to obtain the Output as shown below by combining the numbers in "StateC" column and "CountyC" column but maintain total numbers of 5 digits. (See the column ID in the output table)

How can I achieve this in R?

Thanks in advance.

Table1:

```
Year State StateC County CountyC Yield
1910  NE     1     Adams    1      10.1
1910  NE    31     Arthur  10      20.5
1910  NE    31     Boone   201     30.0
```

Output:

```
Year State StateC County CountyC  Yield    ID
1910  NE     1     Adams    1      10.1   31001
1910  NE    31     Arthur  10      20.5   31010
1910  NE    31     Boone  201      30.0   31201
```

Comment: `sprintf()` can do that. `Table1$ID <- sprintf("%02d%03d", Table1$StateC, Table1$CountyC)`

Comment: I am new to R. Can you show me how?

Comment: Check `?sprintf` and show us what you've tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a task for `sprintf()`:

```
Table1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'Year State StateC County CountyC Yield
1910  NE    31     Adams   1       10.1
1910  NE    31     Arthur  10      20.5
1910  NE    31     Boone   201     30.0')
Table1
Table1$ID <- sprintf("%02d%03d", Table1$StateC, Table1$CountyC)
Table1
#   Year State StateC County CountyC Yield    ID
# 1 1910    NE     31  Adams       1  10.1 31001
# 2 1910    NE     31 Arthur      10  20.5 31010
# 3 1910    NE     31  Boone     201  30.0 31201
```

Comment: What if I have "StateC" with 1 digit?

Comment: `sprintf("%02d%03d", 1, 22)` gives "01022" https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html

Answer (score 0):

The way to directly answer the question in the title is to use `str_pad` from the [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf) package:

```
Table1$ID = with(Table1,paste(StateC,str_pad(CountyC,3,pad="0"),sep=""))
```

The function call `str_pad(CountyC,3,pad="0")` pads the numbers in the `CountyC` column so that they are 0-padded to have length 3. The `sprintf()` solution of @jogo is more concise (and deserves to be accepted), but if you are new to R and anticipate that you will be doing a lot of string manipulation then it is good to know about `stringr`

Answer (score 0):

We could do this arithmetically

```
Table1$ID <- with(Table1, 1e3*(StateC+CountyC/1e3))
Table1$ID
#[1] 31001 31010 31201
```

Or as @MatthewLundberg suggested, another simple variation is

```
Table1$ID <- with(Table1, 1e3*StateC + CountyC)
```

Comment: Simpler: `1e3*StateC + CountyC`